# How can I find the unit vector between a point and a line?

Tags: math, vector, rotational-matrices

I have three known **3-Dimensional** points: `A`, `B`, and `C`.

Addtionally, I have a fourth point, `X`.

`X` lies on vector `AB` such that vector `CX` is perpendicular to vector `AB`. So `AB · CX = 0`

How do I find the unit vector of CX?

---

The use-case here is that I am constructing a (translated) rotational matrix, where the origin is A, the z-axis passes through B, the xz-plane passes thtough C, and the axes are orthogonal

I also have a vector object that provides dot and cross product functions at my disposal.

Comment: I don't think this is a good fit for Stack Overflow, it's more about mathematics than anything else.

Comment: It's too elementary for math overflow.  Besides, it's hardly advanced. Why not take a crack at it?

Comment: I've attempted to take a crack at it, but I'm not getting anywhere yet...

Comment: I meant that people should take a crack at answering.  I think it's a valid enough question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

```
U = (B-A)/||(B-A)||
```

be a unit vector along the line from A to B, where `||X||` denotes the length of vector `X`.  Now we can parameterize the entire line by

```
A + tU
```

and we want

```
((A + tU) - C)*U = 0
```

so that

```
A*U - C*U + t = 0
t = C*U - A*U
```

so we've solved for `t`, and now we let

```
V = (A+tU - C)/||A+tU - C||
```

and we have our unit vector along the line, `U`, and one orthogonal to it, `V`.

Comment: Does `A*U` denote the dot or cross product?

Comment: So `V = (A + (C·U - A·U) * U - C)/||(A + (C·U - A·U) * U - C)||`?

Comment: @Eric - `*` is the dot product, and yes, you've expanded it correctly.

Comment: Which is equivalent to normalizing `((A - C) + (C - A)·U * U)`?

Comment: (Note - thanks to @Mouagip for noticing the missing `||` in the first equation.)